# Will we see Angel of Death when we're dying?

Tags: death, malaikah

When we are dying, will we see Malak al Maut as we lay in our deathbed or is that a myth? Also how is it possible that he's takes the souls of multiple people around the world at once? Is he the only angel that takes the souls or is there more? Jazkallah for whoever asked this question, answers it or even views it. May Allah swt guide us all and bless us with jannat al firdous allahuma ameen.

Comment: According my understanding of the qur'an there's no one Malak al-Mawt, but each of us will have an assigned one at the time of death. Please use meaningful and relevant tags in future (I've edited your post)!

Answer (score 1):

For every soul, there is a separate Angel of death:

> Say, “The angel of death who has been assigned for you will take your
> soul in full, then you will be brought back to your Lord.” - [Quran 32:11]

And about whether you will **see** angel of death on your deathbed or not, you will only know when you will die.

Comment: From the details which have been mentioned at other places in the Quran, it is believed that the chief angel of death has a whole staff of the angels under him, who perform a variety of duties in connection with causing the death, seizing the soul and taking it into custody. Moreover, their treatment of a guilty soul is different from their treatment of a believing, righteous soul. (For details, see (Surah An-Nisa: Ayat 97), (Surah Al-Anaam: Ayat 93), (Surah An-Nahl: Ayat 28), (Surah Al-Waqiah: Ayats 83-94).